# Join multiple table in Java Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm, join

I am having problem with joining tables in Java Spring hibernate. Here is my problem :

I am developing a web site and in one of my page I need the data from three tables, they are x, y, z. I mapped each of them in to entity and has its own repository. In this page I am showing the data using this query :

```
SELECT x.a, y.b, z.c FROM x,y,z WHERE x.id = y.name AND z.id = y.personalId AND
(x.id like %'searchedId'% or y.id like %'searchedId'% or z.id like %'searchedId'%) AND
(x.name like %'searchedName'% or y.name like %'searchedName'% or z.name like %'searchedName'%)
```

The problem is, the searchedId and searchedName is an optional column and they could be empty string and when they are empty strings I don't need to  put them into my query to speed it up. I tried using criteria builder but since the result is joined column from multiple tables I can't put them into any repository.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can then dynamically build native query something like below:

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("SELECT x.a, y.b, z.c FROM x,y,z WHERE x.id = y.name AND z.id = y.personalId ");

if (searchId !=null)
    query .append(" AND
(x.id like %'searchedId'% or y.id like %'searchedId'% or z.id like %'searchedId'%) ");

if (searchedName !=null)
    query .append(" AND
(x.name like %'searchedName'% or y.name like %'searchedName'% or z.name like %'searchedName'%) ");

SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(query);
List result = query.list();
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't see your dynamically build query. Maybe you forgot to put them.

Comment: I have added it now.You can create a nativeSQL query and only when searchId and searchName wont be null they will be added to the main query.

Comment: And how should I execute it? I mean should I put in a repository? And what would be the return value? Sorry, I am new in this.

Comment: You can directly run using  session.createSQLQuery(query).list() , no need to put in a repository.

Comment: I just realize what do you mean. Ok I am trying it now

Comment: You have to call session.createSQLQuery(query);  . once you get a Query object, then you can call list() method on it to get results . you can create this method in a DAO class .

Comment: I tried using StringBuilder and got exception = Required java.lang.StringBuilder but found java.lang.String even though I have imported java.lang.StringBuilder. When I am using String for the query I got the null exception in Query query = session.createSQLQuery(query);. Did I miss something?

Comment: What is the type of session which you use to createSQLQuery? And how do I initialize it?

Comment: session is of type org.hibernate.Session and you can create it through by calling sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() and since you are using spring you can inject sessionfactory.